# How to load all cPickle dumps from a log file?

Tags: python, zlib, pickle

I'm going to be running code that will be writing a large number (~1000) of relatively small (50 key:value pairs of strings) dictionaries to a log file. I'll be doing this through a program that automates this. I'm thinking of running a command like:

```
import random
import string
import cPickle as pickle
import zlib

fieldNames = ['AICc','Npix','Nparameters','DoF','chi-square','chi-square_nu']

tempDict = {}
overview = {}
iterList = []

# Create example dictionary to add to the log.
for item in fieldNames:
  tempDict[item] = random.choice([random.uniform(2,5), '', ''.join([random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(5)])])

# Compress and pickle and add the example dictionary to the log.
# tried  with 'ab' and 'wb' 
# is .p.gz the right extension for this kind of file??
# with open('google.p.gz', 'wb') as fp: 
with open('google.p.gz', 'ab') as fp:
  fp.write(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(tempDict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL),9))

# Attempt to read in entire log
i = 0
with open('google.p.gz', 'rb') as fp:
  # Call pickle.loads until all dictionaries loaded. 
  while 1:
    try:     
      i += 1
      iterList.append(i)
      overview[i] = {}
      overview[i] = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(fp.read()))
    except:
      break

print tempDict
print overview
```

**I'd like to be able to load the last dictionary written to the log file (google.p.gz), but it currently only loads the first pickle.dump**.

Also, is there a much better way to do everything that I'm doing? I've searched around and it feels like I'm the only one doing anything like this, and I've found that to be a bad sign in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input and output do not match. When you output your records, you take each record individually, pickle it, compress it, and write the result individually to the file:

```
fp.write(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(tempDict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL),9))
```

but when you input your records, you read the *whole file*, uncompress it, and unpickle a single object from it:

```
pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(fp.read()))
```

So the next time you call `fp.read()` there's nothing left: you read the whole file the first time.

So you have to match your input to your output. How to do this depends on your exact requirements. Let's suppose that your requirements are:

1. There will be so many records that the file needs to be compressed on disk.
2. All the records get written to the file in one go (you have no need to append individual records).
3. You do not need random access to records in the file (you will always be happy to read the entire file in order to get to the last record).

With these requirements, it is a bad idea to compress each record individually with [`zlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html). The [DEFLATE algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) used by `zlib` works by finding repeated sequences and so works best for large amounts of data. It won't do much for a single record. So let's use the [`gzip`](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) module to compress and decompress the whole file.

I made a few other improvements to your code as I went through it.

```
import cPickle as pickle
import gzip
import random
import string

field_names = 'AICc Npix Nparameters DoF chi-square chi-square_nu'.split()

random_value_constructors = [
    lambda: random.uniform(2,5),
    lambda: ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase)
                    for x in xrange(random.randint(0, 5)))]

def random_value():
    """
    Return a random value, either a small floating-point number or a
    short string.
    """
    return random.choice(random_value_constructors)()

def random_record():
    """
    Create and return a random example record.
    """
    return {name: random_value() for name in field_names}

def write_records(filename, records):
    """
    Pickle each record in `records` and compress them to `filename`.
    """
    with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for r in records:
            pickle.dump(r, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def read_records(filename):
    """
    Decompress `filename`, unpickle records from it, and yield them.
    """
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                return
```